# Set specific Abstract LCD Density (312) in emulator

Tags: android

I want to configure HTC One Plus emulator whose configurations are shown here: http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_x-4320.php

Now while creating an emulator, I want to set Abstracted LCD density as 312, but It is not changing it. It is showing 120, 160, 240, 320 dpi. But I want to set a customize LCD density as 312.

I researched a lot in this and found nothing. Please suggest!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do this in Motodev in Mac version,I have added the screenshot of the sample emulator created below.But I find very much difficult & no other option in the current ADT available.

[image]

Comment: But how can I do the same in my machine. How do you able to change "Abstract LCD density" parameter???

Comment: What sort of system do you have?

Comment: probably he uses Eclispe under Windows because even I can not find how to set it with AVD installed for Windows.